# How to use if else comparing string in a batch file?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I would like to check the string is match or not. I tried this way, but it always return error, syntax error, I don't know which syntax that error.
Error message

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> if TXT EQU TXT(

```
SET Format=TXT
REM ECHO %Format%

if %Format% EQU TXT(
ECHO Format correct
GOTO END
)

ECHO Format not correct
```

Comment: The parenthesis is being included in the second term, so there appears to be no instruction to execute giving a syntax error. Insert a space before the `(`

Comment: @Magoo yes, you are correct, need add space before ( . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@echo off
set format=TXT
if "%format%"=="TXT" (
@echo Format correct
goto :end
)
@echo Format not correct
:end
```